# Two power series have the same radius of convergence using Abel

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, power-series

I have a question about this proof:

> Prove that the two power series
>
> $$\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_nz^n\quad \text{ and }\quad \sum_{i=0}^\infty na_nz^{n-1}$$
>
> have the same radius of convergence, by using only Abel’s Lemma.

I tried showing that if $\|a_nz_0^n\|$ is bounded then $\|na_nz_0^{n-1}\|$ is also bounded and therefore both series will have the same radius of convergence. Is this a reasonable way to approach the problem?

(Abel's Lemma: Take $z_0 \ne 0$. If $\|a_nz_0^n\|$ is bounded ($\leqslant M$) for all natural $n$ then $\forall r$ s.t. $0\leqslant r \leqslant |z_0|$, $\sum_{i=0}^\infty \|a_n\|z^n$ is convergent.)

Comment: Sorry about that, I included the direction I was approaching the problem so far

Comment: I don’t see why you would use Abel’s lemma for thid when it follows directly from the fact that the radius of convergence of $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n z^n$ is $1/\limsup_n |a_n|^{1/n}$.